# Is there a way (in vanilla javascript) to prevent duplication of rng-generated objects within one array that match multiple keys?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, constructor

I'm fairly new to JS, so please bear with me as I struggle through this explanation:

I start with an empty `array = []`

I'm using a `for` loop in conjunction with an object constructor to generate a specified number of objects - each of which has the same set of keys - and using several rng functions to assign random values to each key within each generated object. These objects get `push`ed one at a time at the end of each loop to the empty array from earlier.

Each object generated has 6 keys in total.

I want to know if it's possible to prevent the generation of a new object if it would match a specific subset of keys. I.e, if I have

```
object = {key1: 17,
          key2: 'potato',
          key3: false,
          key4: true,
          key5: 27,
          key6: 'purple flamingos'
}
```

I want to ensure that the function does not generate any more elements with exactly the following combination of values:

```
key1: 17,
key2: 'potato',
key4: true,
```

Though any two of them can match, I want to prevent exactly those three key/value pairs from ever repeating in the resulting array.

---

Here's more of my code, if that helps

```
"use strict";

const quizSubmissions = []; // Empty array for randomly generated student list

function Submission(quizName, quizModule, quizScore, studentId, studentName, submissionDate) { // Constructor for individual submissions
    this.quizName = quizName,
        this.quizModule = quizModule,
        this.quizScore = quizScore,
        this.studentId = studentId,
        this.studentName = studentName,
        this.submissionDate = submissionDate
}

const randQuiz = (a, b) => { // Output quiz name and module based on input
}

const randQuizScore = () => { // Generate random quiz grade from 50 to 100
}

const randStudent = (c) => { // Output student name and id based on input
}

const randSubmissionDate = () => { // Generate random dare of submission
}

const generateStudentList = (quantity) => { // Function to generate submission objects with rng
    console.log('Values automatically stored to array named "quizSubmissions"')

    for (let i = 0; i < quantity; i++) { // Iterate through the loop 'quantity' times
        let a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
        let b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
        let c = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);

        quizSubmissions.push(
            new Submission(
                randQuiz(a, b)[0],
                randQuiz(a, b)[1],
                randQuizScore(),
                randStudent(c)[1],
                randStudent(c)[0],
                randSubmissionDate())) // Push new object to global array, based on rng results
    }

    return quizSubmissions;
}

const clearStudentList = () => {
    quizSubmissions.length = 0;
}
```

Comment: Generate the object in a loop, and each iteration verify that the values you wish to guarantee don't duplicate an existing object in the array. You verify by using `Array.some` function. The loop terminates when the verification is done. Can you figure out how? Or need pseudo code?